# CVVMask=true option not working to peach payment gateway?

Tags: angularjs

I have used on peach payment gateway.Credit card CVV Placeholder option is not masking on peach payment screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue.I have updated the below code,
var wpwlOptions = {
  maskCvv: true,
} 
from index.html page.The CVV number are masked successfully.